# ASP MVC Get Controller/Action Name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, how can I get the controller/action name base on request URL?

Url example: http://contoso.com/View/Comment/1

I want to get:

- "View" as controller name
- "Comment" as action name

Based on `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the parsed information from the routing engine:

```
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
```

Comment: but the ViewContext object doesn't available on controller class or my custom class. I think the only thing I have is HttpContext.Current.Request :-(

Comment: @VanHua: `ControllerContext` has the same property.

Comment: yup, it true that ControllerContext has the same property, in one of my custom class (class MyCustomRoute : RouteBase) the ControllerContext still null. All I need is create a generic method to get my goal, so I think base on the Current.Request or something like that is the only way :-(

Comment: @VanHua: Doesn't the RouteBase method take a RequestContext as a parameter? If you can't get the existing RequestContext, your only option is to re-run the routing logic.